# How to implement session management with WebFluxSecurity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am new to webfluxsecurity and I have been trying to implement the session management and I am using OKTA for authentication. I have found the below answers -
To kick out the old login with a new login, we only need to set the maximum number of sessions to 1. The configuration is as follows:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1);
    }
```

do we have any equivalent method like sessionManagement() in webfluxsecurity ?
Or any other way we can implement session management in webflux ?

Thanks,